# How to strip slashes in database results in Django..?

Tags: python, django

I have a model class like :

```
class SpUserDetails(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_provider_details' 
        app_label = 'api'
    user = models.ForeignKey(SpUsers, related_name='details') 
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    prof_membership = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    professional_license_number = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    degrees = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    awards_and_publication = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    auth_to_bill_insurence_copany = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    treatment_for_physically_disabled_person = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    specialties = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    offering_at_work_office = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    offering_at_home = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):

        return '{"id":%d,"user_id":%s,"designation":"%s","company_name":"%s","description":"%s","dob":"%s","years_of_experience":"%s","prof_membership":"%s","awards_and_publication":"%s","auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt":"%s","auth_to_bill_insurence_copany":"%s","degrees":"%s","treatment_for_physically_disabled_person":"%s","professional_license_number":"%s","specialties":"%s","offering_at_home":"%s","offering_at_work_office":"%s"}' % (self.id,self.user.id,self.designation, self.company_name,self.description,self.dob,self.years_of_experience,self.prof_membership,self.awards_and_publication,self.auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt,self.auth_to_bill_insurence_copany,self.degrees,self.treatment_for_physically_disabled_person,self.professional_license_number,self.specialties,self. offering_at_home,self.offering_at_work_office)
```

Now i want to strip slashes from `self.description` and i have tried .decode('string_escape') like :

```
def __unicode__(self):
        self.description = self.description.decode('string_escape')
        return '{"id":%d,"user_id":%s,"designation":"%s","company_name":"%s","description":"%s","dob":"%s","years_of_experience":"%s","prof_membership":"%s","awards_and_publication":"%s","auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt":"%s","auth_to_bill_insurence_copany":"%s","degrees":"%s","treatment_for_physically_disabled_person":"%s","professional_license_number":"%s","specialties":"%s","offering_at_home":"%s","offering_at_work_office":"%s"}' % (self.id,self.user.id,self.designation, self.company_name,self.description,self.dob,self.years_of_experience,self.prof_membership,self.awards_and_publication,self.auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt,self.auth_to_bill_insurence_copany,self.degrees,self.treatment_for_physically_disabled_person,self.professional_license_number,self.specialties,self. offering_at_home,self.offering_at_work_office)
```

But its giving following error :

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please help..!!

Comment: I always preceed string with u. The problem here is the formatting string. try with return u'{.....

Comment: If what you want is your `__unicode__()` method to return a suitable json representation of your model instance, you'd be better building a proper `dict` and serializing it with the json module - but then you'd better have a dedicated `to_json` or such method and keep `__unicode__` for internal representation (debug etc).

Comment: @ralf adding u at start didn't made any difference still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After searching alot i've found a solution :

```
def __unicode__(self):
        if self.description is not None:
            self.description = self.description.replace("\\", "")
        return '{"id":%d,"user_id":%s,"designation":"%s","company_name":"%s","description":"%s","dob":"%s","years_of_experience":"%s","prof_membership":"%s","awards_and_publication":"%s","auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt":"%s","auth_to_bill_insurence_copany":"%s","degrees":"%s","treatment_for_physically_disabled_person":"%s","professional_license_number":"%s","specialties":"%s","offering_at_home":"%s","offering_at_work_office":"%s"}' % (self.id,self.user.id,self.designation, self.company_name,self.description,self.dob,self.years_of_experience,self.prof_membership,self.awards_and_publication,self.auth_to_issue_insurence_rem_receipt,self.auth_to_bill_insurence_copany,self.degrees,self.treatment_for_physically_disabled_person,self.professional_license_number,self.specialties,self. offering_at_home,self.offering_at_work_office)
```

It worked perfectly for me..!!